# Form validation to ng-click directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am unable to find the solution with the existing answers,so I am creating new post.

I want to add a validation to button click .

I have the scenario like this,

I have the form with two input fields and one image uploading one,here we have the default image and users also have the chance to upload new one.
if the user not uploaded the image we have to show an error message after click on submit.

```
<div class="form-group">
          <img src="{{ImageUrl}}" class="img-responsive m-b-md" />
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-xs pull-right dash-post-button" aria-label="Post" ng-click="changeImage()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <small>change image</small>
          </button>
          <span ng-show="errImg">please choose the image</span>
        </div>
```

**for image upload:**

```
  $scope.iSupportImageUrl = "images/iceland.jpg";


      var setiSupportImageUrl = function (iSupportImgId) {
          $scope.iSupportImageUrl = AWSBucketNameConverter.getAWSURL('TELEKHA_ISUPPORT_IMG', iSupportImgId);

      };


      $scope.changeiSupportImage = function() {
        var iSupportImgUpldmodalInstance = $modal.open({
            controller: 'EventimageuploadCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/isupportimageupload.html',
            animation: true
        });

        iSupportImgUpldmodalInstance.result.then(
            function (result) {
            setiSupportImageUrl(result.fileId);
            result.status='a';
            result.createdTS='2014-05-04';
            result.containerName='TELEKHA_ISUPPORT_IMG';
            result.createdById=23;
            result.createdName='abc';
            $scope.newiSupport.bannerImage=result
            },
            function () {

            }
        );
      };
```

Comment: so what is the issue now? what do you have inside changeImage

Comment: @Sajeetharan when i click on submit it should show the error message,but now it is submitting.

Comment: just return if there is an error

Comment: @Sajeetharan how do i add ng-required for button

Comment: @Sajeetharan while submitting the error message showing and form also submitting

Comment: Can you show your code to upload new image

Comment: In the changeImage() you may check the what value is set for ImageUrland take appropriate action.

Comment: @Raghav i have updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function like this:

```
$scope.changeImage = function(imageModel){
    if(imageModel){
        // upload the image
    }
    else {
        // Show up the error message
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to add an hidden input field on your img. So you could use required on it. Something along those lines

```
<div
    layout="column"
    flex
    ng-mouseenter="display_icon_picture = true"
    ng-mouseleave="display_icon_picture = false"
    layout-align="center center"
    class="profile-pic-container">
    <img ng-if="profile_picture_url" ngf-src="profile_picture_url">
    <img ng-if="!!!profile_picture_url" class="profile-picture" ngf-src="default_image">
    <md-icon ng-if="display_icon_picture">add_a_photo</md-icon>
</div>
<md-input-container class="form-error" id="Photo" style="font-weight:bold;">
    <input style="display: none;" type="text" ng-model="profile_picture_url" name="Photo" required aria-label="input">
    <div ng-messages="form['Photo'].$error" md-auto-hide="false">
        <div ng-message="required">Requis</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```